# change display:none with jquery with if-else

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've two divs: the div "#Stage" is display="block" and from time to time "display:none". 
Depending on this I'll appear my second div "#case", default is display="none".

So I tried these two ways:

```
if ($('#Stage').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#case').css('display','block')
} // added display:none; to my css file at #case

if ($('#Stage').css('display') == 'none'){
    $('#case').show()
} else if ($('#Stage').css('display') != 'none'){
    $('#case').hide()
}
```

But both of these methods doesn't work, means the #case div is always on display:none.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

THanks

Comment: Can you please add html to the question?

Answer (score 7):

I would use [**:visible**](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) to check if the element is shown or not and use [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method.

```
if ($('#Stage').is(':visible'))    
    $('#case').show();    
else
    $('#case').hide();
```

or

```
if ($('#Stage:visible').length)    
    $('#case').show();    
else
    $('#case').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly because you're using `display:none` in the CSS file, and it's taking precedence. Try doing it inline on `#case` and seeing if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. My two solutions and the first from Adil was working. It was an ordering conflict with Adobe Edge - edgeActions.js.